# Python solve cubic equation using sympy

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation

I am have a problem when trying to solve an equation using `sympy`.
Some of the variables have specific values assigned.
I am trying to solve the equation for `b`,`c` and `d`.
This is my attempt:

```
from random import randint
import sympy
from sympy.abc import b,c,d,B,C,r,x

B=10
C=20
r=123

# Equation: x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d=x^3+(B−r)x^2+(C−B*r)x−C*r
equation = sympy.Eq(x**3+b*x**2+c*x+d,x**3+(B−r)*x**2+(C−B*r)*x−C*r)

print(sympy.solve(equation,"b"))
print(sympy.solve(equation,"c"))    
print(sympy.solve(equation,"d"))
```

Python prints me the following error:

```
    [user@user Python Scripts]$ python polygen.py 
  File "polygen.py", line 10
    equation = sympy.Eq(x**3+b*x**2+c*x+d,x**3+(B−r)*x**2+(C−B*r)*x−C*r)
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you missing a `*` there after `(B-r)`?

Comment: I added the `*` but the error is the exact same.

Comment: try adding a `*` after (C-B*r) too, python doesnt handle inference of multiplication with parenthesis

Comment: @Tissuebox I added it everywhere (See updated start post). Also I tried both, `**` and `^` for power as expression doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `-` character. It's not a regular character for some reason and python isn't recognizing it. I replaced all your minus signs with hyphens on my machine and it works:

```
from random import randint
import sympy
from sympy.abc import b,c,d,B,C,r,x

B=10
C=20
r=123

# Equation: x^3+b*x^2+c*x+d=x^3+(B−r)x^2+(C−B*r)x−C*r
equation = sympy.Eq(x**3+b*x**2+c*x+d,x**3+(B-r)*x**2+(C-B*r)*x-C*r)

print(sympy.solve(equation,"b"))
print(sympy.solve(equation,"c"))
print(sympy.solve(equation,"d"))
```

I'm not sure what kind of character the wrong `-` sign is:

`a = 2−2` does not work in my machine

`a = 2-2` does however

Comment: Oh my god.. That must be have happened by copying the equation from a pdf file. That such a dumb error :D Thanks !

Comment: @Kyu96 That wrong sign is U+2212, a Unicode MINUS SIGN.

Answer (score 2):

`-` IS a MINUS `−` IS NOT. in Python interprets them differently, the first one encodes to `u"\u002D"` but the second encodes to `u"\u2212"` and clearly they won't do the same thing. To be sure use your numeric keyboard.